# Trying to find a good allocation algorithm for a rota

Tags: algorithm, sorting, scheduled-tasks, graph-theory, allocation

Trying to find an allocation problem for a rota of a construction site.

Around 5 construction sites each with 2-4 people needed.
Around 40 construction workers.

Rota must follows these rules:

1. There are multiple construction sites happening at the same time.
2. Every worker can work at every construction site.
3. Every worker has a set of Boolean qualifications. (e.g. canUseDigger, canUseDrill, ...)
4. Each construction site has the need for different qualifications but these needs qualifications will never change.
5. The number of each workers at each site must be fulfilled.
6. Even if a worker is not qualified for any of tasks they can still be put onto a site assuming that all other of the site's requirements are complete.
7. Workers have different availability and can only work 5 days a week at most.

There are few other rules, and could be asked to implement more rules.

All of this information is in a database.

If anyone has had experience in this area before and have a few algorithms that come to mind I would be very thankful to hear them.

If the solution involves AI in some kind that is also a big plus (but is not a necessity)

Links to similar problems with open source solutions would be useful as well.

Thanks for reading.

Wasn't really sure where to start with this one. I was thinking about maybe treating it as a linear programming problem and using Simplex. Wasn't sure if it possible to put into an adjacency matrix either and use something like Hungarian. Someone has recommended bipartite graphs to me.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to programming?

Comment: Need a programmable solution to the problem.

Comment: This is a very classic assignment problem, can probably be written as an [integer linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). Because of the word "integer" in there, the simplex algorithm won't work (the simplex algorithm applies to the simple case of continuous variables, not to the hard case of integer variables). But you don't need to implement the algorithm yourself, just use an existing ILP solver.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not superwell suited for general recommendations, but if you include a very small concrete example in your question, with maybe 2 construction sites and 10 construction workers and 7 days, we can more easily post answers that solve this small example, and then you can work from there for your real situation.

Comment: Also, in general I find https://or.stackexchange.com to be more helpful than stackoverflow for these problems. See for instance [Recommended books material for practical applications of operations research?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/117/recommended-books-materials-for-practical-applications-of-operations-research-in); [Lots of questions about scheduling nurses in hospitals](https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=nurse)

Comment: There are many similar problems, all very similar but each slightly different.  I have worked on numerous such problems.  A few years ago I gathered some code to solve some such problems. ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/schedule ).  You will likely need to adapt this for your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to start is to think of your problem as a collection of jobs which can be completed by assigning resources.

A question that you will need to decide upon is how good a solution you are willing to accept.  The algorithms that guarantee the optimal solution are fiendishly complex and require enormous run times to complete for problems that are larger than half a dozen jobs.  However algorithms with reasonable run times that produce reasonable results ( ~ 90% of the theoretical optimum ) for large problems ( dozens of jobs ) can be found.

I have some open source code at https://github.com/JamesBremner/schedule which can give you some ideas on how to solve a few of these kind of problems.

This input

```
r Alice canUseDrill
r Bob canUseDigger
r Chad canUseDrill
r Derek canUseDigger
r Eric canUseDrill
r Fiona canUseDigger
r George canUseDrill
r Hal canUseDigger
r gw1
r gw2
r gw3
r gw4
r gw5
r gw6
r gw7
r gw8
r gw9
j A 4 canUseDrill canUseDigger
j B 3 canUseDigger
j C 2 canUseDrill
j D 4 canUseDrill canUseDigger
j E 2 canUseDigger
j F 2 canUseDrill
```

generates this output

[image]

Note that in my code every resource ( == worker ) has exactly one type ( == skill ). Your feature 3 ( Every worker has a set of Boolean qualifications ) implies that resources can have multiple types.  This is a significant additional complication, since the algorithm will have to make decisions about which job ( == site ) to assign a worker who has multiple skills in demand at multiple sites.

Perhaps the best way to handle this is to rank the skills in order of decreasing demand and assign workers with high demand skills first.

Comment: I have added option to give workers multiple qualifications.  Detailed documentation at https://github.com/JamesBremner/schedule/wiki/Input-Format.  Nothing clever, just assigning them on a first come, first saved basis.  Contact me if you want to discuss anything more sophisticated,